# Unable to create .feature file in Pycharm Community

Tags: python, pycharm, gherkin, python-behave

I have installed the **Pycharm Community edition** and installed the **behave 1.2.5** with the following command.

```
pip install behave
```

It was successfully installed and it is available in the **Pycharm Project Interpreter** as shown below.

[image: Behave]

But I don't see an option to create the .feature file **(Gherkin file)** when I right click on the project

[image: Gherkin file]

Do I miss anything over here, in Pycharm professional by default Behave BDD is available. How do I configure the behave with Pycharm community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK ["BDD support is available only in the PyCharm Professional Edition."](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-behavior-driven-development-in-pycharm/) 
Of course, nothing prevents you from creating a file with the .feature extension but you are **not** going to see options to run your scenarios. You can get some syntax highlighting using the Gherkin plugin and that is as much as you get in the community edition.

Answer (score 2):

[how to install gherkin plugin on PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jaiy.jpg)

You can access the Settings by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> and install the gherkin plugin. I just did that and is helping a lot.

Comment: Why is this answer not upvoted. I was able to create a feature file in Pycharm by adding Gherkin plugin.