# How to run a feature file using Pycharm Community

Tags: python, pycharm, python-behave

I have installed the behave 1.2.5 and PyCharm Community. When I right click the feature file I do not see an option called **Run as feature file**.

How do I set the Run configuration

[image: Run Configuration]

Comment: BDD support is only available in the Professional version. Look at the feature comparison here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: @idjaw Yes. But in my case, I have to go with Community version. I have installed the behave through **pip**. So how to make the feature file to run

Comment: You are not going to get the BDD feature to work in the Community edition the way you are expecting it to happen. Per the link I specified, the BDD feature is only available in the Professional edition.

Comment: You already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505526/unable-to-create-feature-file-in-pycharm-community). Please do not ask duplicate questions.

Comment: I understand and you are right. But it is a paid one. So I have to go with the Community. Any possibility on running the feature file using Run Configurations.

Comment: Actually I have asked that question for how to get the .feature file in the context menu and this question about running the feature file

Comment: You might want to see if it is possible to do something with the run configuration to run the behave command itself. But I have no idea how feasible that is. I've only used the Professional version. At this point you're probably better off just running the behave command in the command line.

Comment: idjaw ok I will do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have stated, PyCharm community edition is not going to be much help when it comes to behave support. You can however create a testAllFeatures.py with roughly this content:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from behave import __main__ as behave_executable
    behave_executable.main(None)
```

You will get the usual "Run" context menu for this file. Let's call this an *executor* for now as I don't know if there is any wide-spread term for this.
This does the equivalent of executing behave in its directory. You can then play around with tags and a few similar *executors* (with args!=None parameters, of course) to call up different sets of your scenarios.

An alternative is to create "Run configuration(s)" in PyCharm to call the behave cli. The advantage of the above outlined executor approach is that you can run the *executors* even when you are not using PyCharm, including a CI environment.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but maybe other people have this same issue.

You can setup PyCharm Community like this:

Copy Behave Path:

[image]

And paste it in 'Script':

[image]